# JSP-Calling function in a scriplet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp-tags

So, I am trying to validate a user by checking if he is already registered. I am using MySQL for this purpose
My java file *Register.java* is in package *com.aayush.jsp*. Here's a snippet of the file

***Register.java***

```
package com.aayush.jsp;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register {
    public static int check_if_already_exists(String id) {
        ConnectToMySQL connection = new ConnectToMySQL();
        connection.connect();
        try {
            ResultSet rs = connection.stmnt.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM login");
            while(rs.next()) {
                if(id==rs.getString("coumn_name")) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check_if_already_exists("101"));
    }
}
```

Here's the *ConnectToMySQL.java* file:

```
package com.aayush.jsp;
import java.sql.*;
public class ConnectToMySQL {
    Statement stmnt = null;
    public void connect() {
        try {
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/un","root","hellomoto");
            stmnt = myConn.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectToMySQL conn = new ConnectToMySQL();
        conn.connect();
    }
}
```

As you can see, this file uses  a class *ConnectToMySQL* which is defined in the same package. When run as a java application, this code runs fine.

Here's the problem, when I call the method *check_if_already_exists()* from the JSP file as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<% int checkMail = com.aayush.jsp.Register.check_if_already_exists("101");%>
</body>
</html>
```

Apache Tomcat shows up with this error:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /RegisterOrLogin.jsp at line 9

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /RegisterOrLogin.jsp at line 4

1: 
2: <html>
3: <body>
4:  <% int checkMail = com.aayush.jsp.Register.check_if_already_exists("101");%>



Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:579)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.aayush.jsp.Register.check_if_already_exists(Register.java:9)
    org.apache.jsp.RegisterOrLogin_jsp._jspService(RegisterOrLogin_jsp.java:120)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: What is `connection.stmnt`? Check that `stmnt` is not null. This is beside many other issues that are present in your code...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Kindly See the Edit. Thanks.

Comment: Can't see how the NPE can be raised, except if `Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);` raises an error, preventing the execution of `stmnt = myConn.createStatement();`. In that case, can you check your tomcat logs to see if it's failing to connect to the database for some reason? Did you deploy your driver files used to run the app to tomcat as well?

Comment: Yes, I did @ErnestKiwele. As I said, when the java app is executed in isolation, all works fine. But the problem arises when I call the same function from the jsp file.

Comment: I understand that. I don't see what would make the difference, and that's why I think that the issue must be linked to the deployment (either jars were not copied to lib folders or are not bundled in war file)... The most likely place where it fails is that jdbc connection line...

Comment: How do you deploy your JSP to application server? have you checked application server's logs? Have you added dependencies (MySQL driver and all other stuff) to application server lib directory (or packaged inside war file with JSP)? For me it looks like you are missing MySQL dependency and then exception is logged into log file but your application continues to work with `connection.stmnt == null`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was in setting up the dependencies. Working in eclipse can sometimes be combersome. Thanks a lot!